# How to set a already uploaded image as default input(type=file) in the html form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I wanna update an image in my database table. So first I made a MySQL query to display already uploaded Image in the HTML form web page. And after that, I made another query to update Image... So now I want that If I don't choose any Image for the update then **already uploaded Image** should be selected as default input in the form. So How can I set the **already uploaded** image as default input in the form? Please help me out...

```html
<img src="../images/<?php echo $post_image ?>" width="100px">
<input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file">

<!-------------------Display Image--------------------->
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=$post_id ";
    $getPost = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getPost)) {
        $post_image = $row['post'];
    }    
        
?>

<!------------------Update Image------------------->
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['publish_edit'])) {
    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/$post_image");
    
    $query = "UPDATE posts SET ";
    $query .= "post_image = '$post_image' ";
    $query .= "WHERE post_id = $post_id ";
    
    $editPost = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Doing this in HTML is not possible by design. If it were, a page could automatically upload files from any user's disk, which would be a monumental security hazard.

Answer (score 2):

check if the image input is empty or not. if it is empty, leave image database column in it's previous state.